# Replace colors in colormap

Tags: python, replace, colormap, 8-bit, indexed

I use a simple line to break an indexed image 256 color into palette using

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('')
palette = np.array(im.getpalette(),dtype=np.uint8).reshape((256,3))

#####################
Printed result
[[  1   3   0]
[  2   4   1]
 [ 28   0   4]
 [ 20   2  26]
 [ 24   5  18]
 [ 33   7  22]
 [ 36   7  12]
 [  0  20  18]
 [ 42  15  16]
 [ 43  18  30]
```

... etc

Printing 'palette' lists the colors as RGB values as listed from index 0 onward. Index 0 is often dark color or black. In some engines it is used for alpha, transparency. I want to use commonly used colors for transparency like Magenta 255 0 255

I want to take each of my png files in a folder and do batch (I will have to manually add the color to the images, then save them as 8 bit so the color is part of the palette) then do:

- exchange position of index 0 color with the Magenta in the color map
- position of magenta color will vary for each file, just find the color 255 0 25 and replace color at index 0 with it but also take the index 0 color and put it on magenta place
- do for all .png files in folder with a single run (magenta will be added and images indexed before running the script)
  [image]

[image: This is an image where Magenta isnt first color of image palette]
[image: Here is how it should be as final result]

Comment: If, as it seems, you are just starting on this project, why are you using Python 2.7 as it went *"End of Life"* months ago?

Comment: It can be python3 I don't mind, I don't know how to take an item as index when it is with spaces broken into 3 numbers

Comment: Please provide a suitable input image. Thank you.

Comment: What is unsuitable about it? This is a color map, im tring to swap two colors in the palette also listed in the script. How do I find '255 0 255' when it won't read it from the indices even if I printed the index of it, and swap the values with index 0 while put the index 0 values (usually black colors) on the place of where Magenta used to be? And that for all png files in a folder

Comment: It is screen-grab of two different images, and as such is no longer a palette image like you say you have. Instead it is RGB with 411 colours. Secondly, it also has an alpha channel.

Comment: Ok here are two images of that kind, on left u see pure black because ur background is black.But when you swap you see that there is a box in the center. I swapped them manually with Gimp now I want to batch swap them for every image, some images may not have the Magenta at exact same place, so I need to find the Index containing 255 0 255 and swap Index 0 with each other, always Index 0 for all files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open image
im = Image.open('image.png')

# Extract palette
palette = np.array(im.getpalette(),dtype=np.uint8).reshape((256,3))

# Look through palette
for index,entry in enumerate(palette): 
    # Swap this entry with entry 0 if this is magenta
    if index>0 and np.all(entry==[255,0,255]): 
        print(f'DEBUG: Swapping entry {index} with entry 0') 
        palette[0], palette[index] = palette[index], palette[0]
        break
else:
    print('ERROR: Did not find magenta entry in palette')

# Replace palette with new one and save    
im.putpalette(palette)
im.save('result.png')
```

---

You would probably code it to accept multiple files on the command line like this:

```
for file in sys.argv[1:]:
    ...
    ...
```

Then you could run:

```
UpdatePalette.py *.png
```

Comment: Thanks, that does it.One small correction, replacing 

`palette[0], palette[index] = palette[index], palette[0]`
because it then keeps both Index 0 and Index ... as magenta


. So I used 
            `palette[index] = palette[0]
            palette[0] = 255,0,255`

As it doesn't remember the old color and copies the value to both but putting the 255 0 255 works and looks like in my 'Wanted result'image. Also use 

`sprites = glob.glob('*.png')

for png in sprites:
    # Open image
    im = Image.open(png)`

and     `im.save(im.filename)`

Comment: Cool - glad we got there in the end! Good luck with your project.